# Sanity check for a contour integral, without using Cauchy's Integral Formula

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Problem:

> Evaluate $\int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{z}{(z+2)(z-1)}dz$ , where $\Gamma$ traverses the circle $|z| = 4$ twice in the *clockwise* direction.

As this is supposed to precede my knowledge of [Cauchy's Integral **Formula**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Theorem), I proceed using partial fractions and [Cauchy's Integral **Theorem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_theorem).

---

$$\dfrac{z}{(z+2)(z-1)}=\dfrac{2}{3(z+2)} + \dfrac{1}{3(z-1)} $$
by partial fraction decomposition, so the integral can be split into $$\dfrac{2}{3}\int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{1}{z+2}dz + \dfrac{1}{3} \int_{\Gamma} \dfrac{1}{z-1}dz$$

Now each of these integrals would be equal to $2 \pi i$ - if we were traversing *once* with *positive orientation* -  as the simple poles lie within $\Gamma$  (right?).
But traversing twice gives a factor of $(2)$, and the negative orientation gives a factor of $(-1)$, so we have $$\dfrac{2}{3}(-4 \pi i) + \dfrac{1}{3}(-4 \pi i) = -4\pi i$$

**Is this correct?**

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Not sure what an appropriate "answer" would entail. Maybe I'll just make a CW answer to the effect of "Resolved"... ?

Comment: Seems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

This has been resolved. Thanks.